# Why am I getting this MySQL error with node?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have connected to the database on MySQL, and was able to input data to a table. However, I am not able to input data to another table when it seems that I'm using the exact same method to achieve the input.
Below is the code that works:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 1,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "dg",
    password: "123456",
    database: "legends_database",
    debug: false
});
exports.addUser = (Username, Email, Password, response) => {
    //Build query
    let sql = "INSERT INTO user (Username, Email, Password) " +
    "       VALUES ('" + Username + "','" + Email + "'," + Password +")";
    
    //Execute query
    connectionPool.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err){//Check for errors
            let errMsg = "{Error: " + err + "}";
            console.error(errMsg);
            response.status(400).json(errMsg);
        }
        else{//Send back result
            response.send("{result: 'User added successfully'}");
        }
    });
}
```

I have copied this code and made changes and below is the code that gives me an error.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const connectionPool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 1,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "dg",
    password: "123456",
    database: "legends_database",
    debug: false
});
exports.addPost = (Question_Title, Answer_Paragraph, response) => {
    //Build query
    let sql = "INSERT INTO answer (Question_Title, Answer_Paragraph) " +
    "       VALUES ('" + Question_Title + "','" + Answer_Paragraph  +")";
    
    //Execute query
    connectionPool.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err){//Check for errors
            let errMsg = "{Error: " + err + "}";
            console.error(errMsg);
            response.status(400).json(errMsg);
        }
        else{//Send back result
            response.send("{result: 'Post added successfully'}");
        }
    });
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
Data received: {"Question_Title":"Test_Question","Answer_Paragraph":"Test_Answer"}
{Error: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Test_Answer)' at line 1}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  You're missing a closing ```'``` before the ```)``` in this ```+ Answer_Paragraph  +")";```

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to make queries. Use a prepared statement with placeholders and parameters.

Comment: @ewong You have no idea how big of a help you were. I've been sitting here for about 5 hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and was so done, thank you for taking the time to help me out! means a lot ❤️

Comment: @Barmar made a very valid point, just wanted to add that if you use the user inputs directly in SQL (not using prepared statement + parameters) you are open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: During those 5 hours did you ever do `console.log(sql);` and look around where the error message says "near"? I think you would have seen the missing quote there.

Answer (score 0):

At first writing queries like this is SQL injection prone, so get rid of this. But if you're using for educational/self-use purposes only - here's my point: I see odd number of single quotes so it seems like the error comes from there(The error message just says that you have a syntax error). So try to write your query like this:

```
let sql = `INSERT INTO answer (Question_Title, Answer_Paragraph) VALUES ("${Question_Title}","${Answer_Paragraph}");
```

Comment: That's just a typo and the question should be closed as such, not answered.